Convert TZ format to timestamp in Snowflake
In Snowflake, I have dates in TZ format that I have to convert to regular timestamp without milliseconds. I did some operation, but the output turns out wrong.
Input:
2018-08-12T20:17:46.384Z

Desired Output:
2018-08-12 20:17:46

This is what I did on column ‘Time’.
TO_CHAR(Time::Timestamp yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss)

This produces time in the mentioned format, however the values are wrong. I failed to identify what is the issue. Any help is appreciated.

Hi - please update your question with what you mean by “the values are wrong”. What values did your SQL produce?

Snowflake uses mm for month, mi for minutes. It's why you were seeing 08 for minutes since that's also your month. So just change what you have to this
to_char('2018-08-12T20:17:46.384Z'::timestamp,'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss')

